# How to set again user default for dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, nsuserdefaults

HOW To set user default again to dictionary.

Create the dictionary object and set value to it.

```
NSMutableDictionary * loginDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];
[loginDictionary setValue:@"My Address" forKey:@"ADDRESS_KEY"];
 [loginDictionary setValue:@"1234567890" forKey:@"PHONE_KEY"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newDictionary forKey:@"INFO_KEY"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Now I asses those dictionary value and assign to some other object.

```
    NSDictionary *RetrievedDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"INFO_KEY"];
  txt_Address.text = [RetrievedDictionary objectForKey:@"ADDRESS_KEY"];
  txt_Mobile.text = [RetrievedDictionary objectForKey:@"PHONE_KEY"];
```

How to update?
This is what I try.

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Changed Address" forKey:@"ADDRESS_KEY"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0987654321" forKey:@"PHONE_KEY"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Its not working for me,  Need your small suggestion what i am doing wrong. 
@Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Update the object the way you set... **Change Address is not an object**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSMutableDictionary* changedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"INFO_KEY"]];
 [changedDictionary setObject:@"Changed Address" forKey:@"ADDRESS_KEY"];
 [changedDictionary setObject:@"0987654321" forKey:@"PHONE_KEY"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:changedDictionary forKey:@"INFO_KEY"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary * loginDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[loginDictionary setValue:@"My Address" forKey:@"ADDRESS_KEY"];
[loginDictionary setValue:@"1234567890" forKey:@"PHONE_KEY"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newDictionary forKey:@"INFO_KEY"]; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Your are creating loginDictionary, but adding newDictionary to the NSUserDefaults. Also I would suggest to use constant keys.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 NSMutableDictionary *changedDictionary = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"INFO_KEY"] mutableCopy];
 [changedDictionary setObject:txt_Address.text forKey:@"ADDRESS_KEY"];
 [changedDictionary setObject:txt_Mobile.text forKey:@"PHONE_KEY"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:changedDictionary forKey:@"INFO_KEY"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```